Why is my setInterval for a carousel not working?
I've been trying to make my carousel work with arrows manually and for it to automatically slide as well but the automatic slide part isn't working. The arrows work fine im not sure if they're the issue tho.


let diapositiveActuelle = 1;

afficherDiapositives(diapositiveActuelle);

function diapositiveSuivante(n) {
  afficherDiapositives(diapositiveActuelle += n);
}

function afficherDiapositives(n) {
  let i;
  let diapositives = document.getElementsByClassName("Galerie");

  if (n > diapositives.length) {
    diapositiveActuelle = 1;
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    diapositiveActuelle = diapositives.length;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < diapositives.length; i++) {
    diapositives[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  diapositives[diapositiveActuelle - 1].style.display = "block";
}

setInterval(function() {
  diapositiveActuelle++;
  afficherDiapositives(diapositiveActuelle);
}, 3000);
.Galerie {
  display: none
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.Carousel {
  max-width: 70%;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  transition: scale 1000ms;
  cursor: zoom-in;
}

.Carousel :hover {
  scale: 110%;
}

.avant,
.suivant {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -10vh;
  color: white;
  font-size: 3vh;
}

.suivant {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}
<div class="Carousel">

  <div class="Galerie " style="display: block;">

    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="Galerie ">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="Galerie ">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="Galerie ">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?grayscale" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="Galerie ">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/870/200/300?grayscale&blur=2" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="Galerie ">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?blur" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <a class="avant" onclick="diapositiveSuivante(-1)">&#10094</a>
  <a class="suivant" onclick="diapositiveSuivante(1)">&#10095</a>

</div>




do you get any errors in console?

What steps have you taken to debug it?

"it just doesn't work" isn't particularly helpful. What are you expecting and what's actually happening? What are the symptoms of it not working?

@blurfus hi, i don't get any errors

@mykaf hi, i want the setInterval to autoplay my carousel, sliding the images automatically. everything else works fine except the setInterval isn't autoplaying the slides.

What steps have you taken to debug it? When I run your code, it seems to work as expected.

seems working as @mykaf said
